# Mots d'origine religieuse (p.ex. bible, hagiographie) et leur emploi métaphorique

Tags: sens, usage, religion

> Rien n’est dit à ce sujet autre que l'**éloge** habituel.
>
> Mais ce n'est qu'un travail de science et pas une **bible**.
>
> Tous ceux qui sont habitués à l'**hagiographie** habituelle de la science seront choqués.

De nos jours, peut-on employer ces mots même hors du contexte religieux ?

Comment: Une hagiographie doit traiter d'une personne, outre ça l'usage est naturel.

Comment: @LukeSawczak : Oui assurément mais quand on entre dans l'extension de sens... on ne s'arrête pas. Tout est personnifiable... la science au premier chef... à ce qu'il semble...rait : https://lejournal.cnrs.fr/personnification  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En général, je ne connais pas de terme primitivement employé dans un contexte religieux qui ne puisse être utilisé hors de ce contexte.

Il peut s'agir d'un emploi *figuré* ou alors, comme pour *hagiographie* d'un emploi *par extension* comme le souligne le [DAF](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/hagiographie?page=1) :

"*Biographie ou ensemble de récits qui présente la vie d'un personnage sous son meilleur jour ou qui l'embellit. L'hagiographie napoléonienne.*"

Answer (score 2):

Beaucoup de mots et d'expressions d'origine religieuse sont couramment utilisés hors de ce contexte-là: *prêcher pour sa paroisse*, *sacrifier [quelque chose] sur l'autel [d'autre chose]*, faire du *ramdam*, les *phylactères* chers à la BD, etc.

On peut aussi jouer sur d'autres registres que la religion: juridique: *plaider sa cause*, aéronautique: *avoir des heures de vol*, etc.

Comment: *La messe est dite*, *chemin de croix*, *évangéliser*, *disciples*...

Answer (score 1):

Tout d'abord, je suis d'accord avec les autres réponses qui disent que les exemples fournis sont tout à fait acceptables et que "éloge" n'est pas vraiment un terme religieux. Parler d'un livre de référence comme "une bible" est d'ailleurs très courant (ce sens est même mentionné dans certains dictionnaires).

Cependant, l'emploi de termes religieux comme interjection les fait souvent passer dans la catégorie des jurons. Il faut donc veiller à ne pas généraliser leur usage en dehors du contexte religieux car cela peut (encore) choquer.

Answer (score 0):

On  trouve  dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hagiographie) le mot « hagiographie » en emploi par extension mais pas le mot  « eulogie » dont les usages se situent seulement au niveau de la religion; on y trouve cependant solidement établi en emploi figuré le mot « bible ». le mot « éloge » n'a pas de connotations religieuses et ne devrait pas figurer dans votre liste.

On peut donc employer le mot « bible » dans tous les cas de livre important traitant un sujet en profondeur, ces classiques qui restent des guides pour l'esprit humain pendant de longues périodes. On peut aussi utiliser « hagiographie » pour les biographies très flatteuses.

> « Le Capital » est la bible du marxiste.

Comment: L'emploi figuré de "hagiographie" est largement attesté.  Voyez le TLFi : "Par extension, biographie excessivement élogieuse."